# dismissViewControllerAnimated sometimes removes navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, navigationbar

I have a MainViewController over which FilterViewController and DetailViewController can be presented when user taps appropriate buttons.
I use the same code to present them:

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I also use the same code to dismiss them from a navigation bar button:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

When FilterViewController is dismissed, everything works like normal, but when DetailViewController is dismissed, navigation bar is removed from MainViewController.

While I can add a block of code to add new navigation bar to MainViewController when DetailViewController is dismissed, I'd very much like to know what could be causing this unusual behaviour?

I know I provided little information to aid in answering this question, but I don't know which parts of code could be relevant for this issue.

**Edit:**

This is the only viewDid method in MainViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.opaque = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0745, green: 0.2667, blue: 0.4471, alpha: 1)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "HeadLogo"))

    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

There are no warnings in the code, only few from ambiguous positions of Storyboard elements.

I don't understand why does dismissal of only DetailViewController remove navigation bar from MainViewController. Other than subview contents, they are basically the same.

**EDIT:**

When returning from DetailViewController, navigation elements are no longer in subview array

Comment: mainviewcontroller viewdidmethods would be helpful, any warnings also,show them

Comment: This is normal and you will always have to dismiss a VC that doesn't contain the navigation bar and then segue to the VC you want.

Comment: Can you tell me how you have added NavigationBar on MainViewController. Is your MainViewController in the UINavigationController. If it is not inside the UINavigationController. I would recommend you to link UINavigationController rootViewController to MainViewController

Comment: @Shashi3456643 I don't have UINavigationController, since all navigation items are custom and there is no actual navigation between view controllers (except these presented view controllers)

Comment: may be your navigation bar is hidden or its coordinate have gone in negative or out of bound. Can u enumerate all subViews of your superview and print all subViews on NSLog and see wether it is there in superView or not.

Comment: What kind of segue are you using?